# How to disable warnings on proc-macros?

Tags: rust

I'm using the [enumflags](https://crates.io/crates/enumflags) crate, which provides the custom derive `EnumFlags` on enums via [enumflags_derive](https://crates.io/crates/enumflags_derive). Additionally, I'm using [Clippy](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rust-clippy) with [`write_literal`](https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#write_literal) enabled.

When deriving a struct with `EnumFlags`, Clippy warns me:

```
warning: writing a literal with an empty format string
    |
    | #[derive(Copy, Clone, EnumFlags)]
    |                       ^^^^^^^^^
    |
    = note: #[warn(write_literal)] on by default
    = help: for further information visit https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/rust-clippy/v0.0.202/index.html#write_literal
```

How can I get rid of this warning without globally disabling the warning?

```
#[cfg_attr(feature = "cargo-clippy", allow(write_literal))]
```

does not work on proc-macros.

Comment: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/48855